How would I clear the comments form when the submit button is pressed? Next-js 14
I am unsure how I would write the code to clear the previous inputted comment in my comment form once the submit button has been pressed, so the user doesn't have to delete the previous input before typing in a new comment. here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated!
I am not sure if I would have to split the page up, and put the comments form in  a seperate components folder, along with the vercel database request.
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import Image from "next/image";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import Link from "next/link";
import { HiPencilAlt } from "react-icons/hi";
import RemoveBtn from "@/app/components/RemoveBtn";
import RemoveBtnComments from "@/app/components/RemoveBtnComments";
export default async function Page({ params }) {
 //get single post
 console.log(params.singlePost);
 const post = (
   await sql`SELECT * FROM posts01 WHERE post_id = ${params.singlePost} `
 ).rows[0];
 const comments = (
   await sql`SELECT * FROM comments01 WHERE post_id = ${params.singlePost}`
 ).rows;
 //handle posts
 async function handleComments(formData) {
   "use server";
   const comment = formData.get("comment");
   const username = formData.get("username");
   await sql`INSERT INTO comments01 (username, comment, post_id)
        VALUES (${username}, ${comment}, ${post.post_id}) `;
   console.log("comment saved");

   revalidatePath(`/allPosts/${params.singlePost}`);
 }
 if (!post) {
   notFound();
 }
 return (
   //display posts
   <>
     {/* //div that contains all */}
     <div>
       {/* //div that contains post */}
       <div>
         <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">{post.title}</h2>
         <div className="flex justify-end gap-5">
           {/* delete post */}
           <RemoveBtn post_id={post.post_id} />
           {/* //edit button */}
           <Link href={`${params.singlePost}/editPost`}>
             <HiPencilAlt size={24} />
           </Link>
         </div>
         <h3 className="text-lg mb-4">{post.content}</h3>
         {/* display image_url */}
         {post.image_url ? (
           <Image
             src={post.image_url}
             alt={`image of ${post.title}`}
             width={300}
             height={300}
           />
         ) : (
           <h3>Image unavailable</h3>
         )}
       </div>
       {/* //comments */}
       <div>
         <h4 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Comments</h4>
         <div className="mb-4">
           <form action={handleComments} className="text-black flex">
             <input
               name="username"
               placeholder="Username"
               value={comments.username}
               className="mr-2 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
             />
             <input
               name="comment"
               placeholder="Comment..."
               value={comments.comment}
               className="flex-1 mr-2 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
             />
             <button
               type="submit"
               className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600"
             >
               Submit
             </button>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div>
           {comments.map((comment) => (
             <div
               className="bg-gray-100 rounded-md p-4 mb-4"
               key={comment.comment_id}
             >
               <p className="font-bold text-lg mb-2">{comment.username}</p>
               <div>
                 <p>{comment.comment}</p>
               </div>
               {/* delete comment */}
               <div className="flex justify-end gap-5">
                 <RemoveBtnComments comment_id={comment.comment_id} />
               </div>
             </div>
           ))}
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </>
 );
}


TL;DR;
Store the comment information in state, and clear the state when comment is submitted.
Container Component Architecture
When creating components, you should always try to separate the component making the api requests from the components with the rendering logic. This is called the Container-Component Pattern.
Currently, the Page component is responsible for interacting with the SQL database, displaying components on the screen and handling user interactions.
Consider the following code.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function PageContainer({ params }) {
  const [postData, setPostData] = useState({});
  const [commentData, setCommentData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      const post = (
        await sql`SELECT * FROM posts01 WHERE post_id = ${params.singlePost} `
      ).rows[0];
      const comments = (
        await sql`SELECT * FROM comments01 WHERE post_id = ${params.singlePost}`
      ).rows;

      setPostData(post);
      setCommentData(comments);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Page
      title={postData.title}
      post_id={postData.post_id}
      content={postData.content}
      image_url={postData.image_url}
      singlePost={params.singlePost}
      comments={commentData}
      submitComment={async ({ post_id, userName, comment }) => {
        // write your insert statement here.x`
      }}
    />
  );
}

function Page({ title, post_id, content, image_url, singlePost, comments, userName, submitComment }) {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('');

  const handleCommentSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Trigger the api request.
    await submitComment({
      post_id,
      userName,
      comment,
    });

    // Clear the inputs.
    setComment('');
  }

  return (
    <>
     <div>
       <div>
         <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">{title}</h2>
         <div className="flex justify-end gap-5">
           <RemoveBtn post_id={post_id} />
           <Link href={`${singlePost}/editPost`}>
             <HiPencilAlt size={24} />
           </Link>
         </div>
         <h3 className="text-lg mb-4">{content}</h3>
         {image_url ? (
           <Image
             src={image_url}
             alt={`image of ${title}`}
             width={300}
             height={300}
           />
         ) : (
           <h3>Image unavailable</h3>
         )}
       </div>
       <div>
         <h4 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Comments</h4>
         <div className="mb-4">
           <form className="text-black flex">
             <input
               name="username"
               placeholder="Username"
               value={userName}
               className="mr-2 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
             />
             <input
               name="comment"
               placeholder="Comment..."
               value={comment}
               onChange={e => setComment(e.target.value)}
               className="flex-1 mr-2 px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
             />
             <button
               type="submit"
               className="px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold rounded-md hover:bg-blue-600"
               onClick={handleCommentSubmit}
             >
               Submit
             </button>
           </form>
         </div>
         <div>
           {comments.map((comment) => (
             <div
               className="bg-gray-100 rounded-md p-4 mb-4"
               key={comment.comment_id}
             >
               <p className="font-bold text-lg mb-2">{comment.username}</p>
               <div>
                 <p>{comment.comment}</p>
               </div>
               <div className="flex justify-end gap-5">
                 <RemoveBtnComments comment_id={comment.comment_id} />
               </div>
             </div>
           ))}
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </>
  );
}


The PageContainer component is responsible for fetching the post and comment data. This data is passed to the Page component. It also passes a submitComment function that runs the insert statement.
The Page component displays all the stuff on the screen. It does not care where the data comes from, or what happens when the comment is submitted.
The Page component stores the user input in a state variable. This value gets cleared in the handleCommentSubmit method after the submitComment completes.
I would also suggest that you break the design into even smaller components -

Image - display the image, and the text when not present.
CommentForm - display the form and handle the state and submit functionality
CommentList - display all comments based on list of comments provided.

